# Starting multiple instances of the same Activity from Service

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent, android-activity

I want to start multiple instance of the same `Activity` class from a `Service`. The reason I'm doing this, is because I have a `Service` that runs a "scan" daily, and if it finds any malfunctions it should display a popup for each malfunction.

The `Activity` that I'm starting is more like a `Dialog`, has a `Dialog theme` to display info about the malfunction.

Manfiest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".ui.dialogs.MalfunctionActivity"
   android:theme="@style/MyDialog"
   android:launchMode="standard">
```

Intent to start the activity from `Service`:

```
    Intent displayMalf=new Intent(this, MalfunctionActivity.class);
    displayMalf.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(displayMalf);
```

**PROBLEM:** to start the `Activity` from a `Service` I need the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` which somehow cancels the `launchMode="standard"` from the manifest, and gives me just one `Activity` even if I try to start multiple diffrent instances.
Is there anyway in which I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm generally a little uncomfortable a Service being able to generate what is effectively a popup dialogue regardless of what the user is doing. I'd prefer any app which needs to notify me of anything to use Status Bar Notifications http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: I totally agree. But it is somehow an "in-house" app, and it is a "requirement" not a decission of my own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was so simple. There is the flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK) which according to the documentation :

> Used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to disable the behavior of bringing an existing task to the foreground. When set, a new task is always started to host the Activity for the Intent, regardless of whether there is already an existing task running the same thing.

Was exactly what I need. Thanks and sorry for answering on my question. It is not a habit. :)

Comment: I did this, `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);` but still I get only one instance. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

Service will take the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to start the activity but here you can try like this:

1. Set the `instance of the handler` of the activity of which you want multiple instances, in the service.
2. When you want the new instance of the activity use `handler.sendMessage(msg)` and on receiving this msg in your activity, start this activity again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your app works in the background and will display the popups even if the app is not in the foreground at the moment, right?

Otherwise I would use normal popup's (AlertViews) instead of starting new activities all the time.

If the app works in the background, you could tell the user with the first popup that your app has found one or more malfunctions and that he should activate the app for more details